# associations in rails from front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `User` and `Group` model.  `User` `has_many` `Groups` and `Group` `belongs_to` `User`

I already have entries in the user table:

```
id    name
--------------
1     testuser
2     someotheruser
```

Imagine if the user with id `1 (testuser)` is logged in and I want to create groups inside that user.

When I create a new group from new action in Group Controller the entries in the DB are going like this:

```
   id   groupname   user_id
   ------------------------
   1    groupA
   2    groupB
```

as you see, user_id, column is always going in as blank so the association is not there.

What do I need to do to make this association?

code for `GroupsController`:

```
  def new
    @group = Group.new
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.new(params[:group])
    if @group.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created group."
      redirect_to groups_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

code for `views/groups/new.html.erb`

```
<% title "New Group" %>

<% form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>


<p><%= link_to "Back to List", groups_path %></p>
```

I am new to rails please tell me how to make association with the user.   From the console I am able to make the association by adding groups for a user like this:

```
@u = User.find(1)
@u.groups.create(:groupname=>"groupA")
@u.save
```

but I dont know how to get this done from the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to make sure that a group can't be saved without a user:

**/app/models/group.rb**

```
class Group
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

Then, lets default the group to be the current user.

**/app/controllers/groups_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(params[:group])
  @group.user = current.user
  if @group.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

You could also do a `@group.user = current_user if @group.user.nil?` but it sounds like the only person to create a group will be the current user.

Comment: thanks I'll try this. I was going to try the approach of passing the hidden field with user_id but this is much better

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your user id is part of the params passed to Group.new, perhaps something like this:

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(params[:group].merge!({:user_id => current_user}))
  if @group.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created group."
    redirect_to groups_url
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

You may want to add a flash[:error] in your else clause as well otherwise it would be confusing to the user to end up on the new action with no explanation.